# How to call JavaScript class instance method from DOM event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple JavaScript "class":

```
function Person(params) 
{
    this.name = params.name;
}
Person.prototype.SayHi = function()
{
    alert(this.name + " says hi");
}
```

This works as expected when I run it in place. Running the following code gives me a popup that says "Alice says hi":

```
var alice = new Person({name:"Alice"});
alice.SayHi();
```

But when I try to assign it to a button event, it won't work:

```
$("#AliceOnClick").on("click", alice.SayHi);
$("#BobOnClick").on("click", bob.SayHi);
```

It appears that the `SayHi` function gets called, but the `name` field is null.

Minimal working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AKHsc/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run it in an anonymous function to invoke it. Since you're calling a method on the object, you need parenthesis.

```
$(function(){
    $("#AliceOnClick").on("click", function() {
        alice.SayHi();
    });
    $("#BobOnClick").on("click", function() {
        bob.SayHi();
    });
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FY4xs/) here.

Answer (score 13):

jQuery sets the receiver of the event handler to the target element, so that you can conveniently do something like `$(this).hide()`.

You can use e.g. `$.proxy` to work around it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#AliceOnClick").on("click", $.proxy(alice.SayHi, alice));
    $("#BobOnClick").on("click", $.proxy(bob.SayHi, bob));
});
```

Comment: Indeed. Event listener (both native JavaScript and jQuery) execute the event handler in the `context` of the element being clicked. Effectively the same as setting the first parameter of `Function.prototype.apply` to the DOM element. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: To elaborate on my comment above, basically the `context` is what `this` is set to. So, in using the `Function.prototype.apply` method, you can determine what the `this` variable is for that specific execution. This can be illustrated further with the following: `function sayHi(){ alert(this.name + "says Hi"; }; sayHi.apply(alice); sayHi.apply(bob);`

Answer (score 1):

So, you call the function without invoking it through `instance`, and the javascript doesn't maintain a link between the `instance object` and the functions, just pass the instance object to the function.

```
function Person(params) 
{
    this.name = params.name;
}
// version 1
Person.prototype.SayHi = function(who)
{
    return function() {
        alert(who.name + " says hi");
    }
}
// version 2, with `bind` method supported
Person.prototype.SayHi = function () {
    return function () {
        alert(this.name + " says hi");
    }.bind(this);
}
// version 3
Person.prototype.SayHi = function () {
    var who = this;
    return function () {
        alert(who.name + " says hi");
    }
}

alice = new Person({
    name: "Alice"
});
bob = new Person({
    name: "Bob"
});

$(function(){
    $("#AliceOnClick").on("click", alice.SayHi()));
    $("#BobOnClick").on("click", bob.SayHi());
    // $("#AliceOnClick").on("click", alice.SayHi(alice));
    //$("#BobOnClick").on("click", bob.SayHi(bob));
});
```

Comment: In your code you don't need the `who` parameter - the instances are available as `this` in the `SayHi` method that returns the handler.

Comment: @Bergi I would double check that. Would not the this context be the owner of the element that fired the event?

Comment: @eggmatters: I mean `var who = this;` instead of taking it as a parameter to `function SayHi(who)`

Comment: yes that's correct, `who = this` is needed. Towry has provided some excellent examples here. I completely forgot about bind.